# To get two mice data the same time by using Raw Input

Tags: c++, winapi, mouseevent, mouse, raw-input

Raw input could get two mice data, but if two mice are moved by the user simultaneously, it seems I can only get the data of the mouse being detected first and cannot get the movement information of another mouse.

To get the mouse information of different mice, this is what I did:

```
PeekMessage( &msg, c_handle, WM_INPUT, WM_INPUT, PM_NOREMOVE) != 0

GetRawInputData(    (HRAWINPUT)msg.lParam, RID_INPUT, lpb, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) != dwSize  )
```

So, when the first mouse handle is being peeked, the second mouse can only be detected after the operation on the first mouse is stopped.

The [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546(v=vs.85).aspx) talked about using Buffered Read for devices that can produce large amounts of raw input. But this method has many problems itself and should only work for multiple inputs on a single mouse (device)

Not sure how to peek two mouse handles and get two mouse data when they are moved simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using PM_NOREMOVE is causing an issue. I suggest either using GetMessage() or PM_REMOVE. What you are describing should not be a problem, as I have done something similar and not had this issue.

Also make sure you are calling DefRawInputProc() at the end of the wndproc message.

Comment: So, I should still use GetRawInputData instead of GetRawInputBuffer ?

Comment: Both should work fine. I used GetRawInputData in my implementation. You will still need to call DefRawInputProc().

Comment: I agree that `PM_NOREMOVE` is the culprit. You can't peek multiple messages of the same type, `PM_NOREMOVE` simply peeks the first available message and leaves it in the queue, so if you try to peek again then you will get the same message. You have to remove the message from the queue in order to move forward to the next message. For that matter, you probably should not be peeking messages at all.  Let your normal message loop dispatch the messages to your target window's wndproc normally.

Comment: I am using OpenSceneGraph, and maybe can only use PeekMessage to get the information on the window. And after adding     GetRawInputBuffer(buffer, &dataRead, HEADERSIZE);     DefRawInputProc(pBuffer, dataRead, HEADERSIZE); after PeekMessage, my program crashed.

Comment: You should only use DefRawInputProc if you pull the message off the queue with PM_REMOVE or GetMessage()

Comment: DefRawInputProc needs an array of RAWINPUT structures for its first argument. It seems I need to call GetRawInputBuffer to get the array of RAWINPUT.